# Cant get the data from my database(MongoDB) to output on my site

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im trying to fetch data from my mongoDB database. And output them on a simple website, cant figure out how though. I got it to work when i used "dummy data" That I inputed directly into an `contactlist` array. And simply fetched them.

But now I have simple database that includes:

```
[ { _id: 5880e3a737893c04c87e30bf,
    name: 'Tom',
    email: 'Tom@msn.com',
    number: '4444444444' },
  { _id: 5880e44637893c04c87e30c0,
    name: 'Tracy',
    email: 'Tracy@asodj.com',
    number: '123412345' },
  { _id: 5880e44637893c04c87e30c1,
    name: 'tucker',
    email: 'tucker@email.com',
    number: '1234456666' } ]
```

`server.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('contactlist', ['contactlist']);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get('/contactlist', function(req, res){

    db.contactlist.find(function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
    });

});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server running on port 3000");
```

`controller.js:`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/contactlist').success(function(response){
        console.log("I got the data i requested");
        $scope.contactlist = response.data;
    });

}]);
```

`index.html:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Contact List App</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="containter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <h1>Contact List App</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Number</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactlist">
                    <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.number}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So my error is that the output on my site is (for like 1ms): `{{contact.name}} {{contact.email}} {{contact.number}}`

Comment: do you have an error or something ?

Comment: @Derlin Sorry, lol. Updated it.

Comment: You mean that it shows the brackets for some time and then shows the proper values ?

Comment: And then nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the brackets showing on load, this is often a problem with angularJS. It takes some time to load/initialise, so the raw brackets/text are visible for some time. Nothing to worry about.

In your code, you return directly the result of `db.find`. From the doc, `find()` returns a *cursor*, not an array. Try this:

```
app.get('/contactlist', function(req, res){
    db.contactlist.find().toArray(function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

UPDATE: the real problem is in the js side.

```
 $http.get('/contactlist').success(function(data) {
   // data is your array here !
   // so data.data will be undefined...
 });
```

`.success` is a shortcut, but normally `.get` returns a promise that you use with `.then`:

```
$http.get('/contactlist').then(function(response) {
   // here, response has a status, data and error field
});
```

I strongly advise you to have a look at [this article](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/) for more information. Also, with angularJS, using a `$resource` service is always cleaner. Here is [one of the many tutorials available](https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/).

Comment: Sorry, but that didnt work either. Same as before. Whats a cursor, in this context?

Comment: a cursor is a sort of iterator that allows you to access/navigate through the data returned by the query. What does the contactlist returns ? Have a look at the "network" tab of your developer console. Also, what does the `console.log(docs)` print ?

Comment: Alright, thx. So it does return the correct json data: `[{"_id":"5880e3a737893c04c87e30bf","name":"Tom","email":"Tom@msn.com","number":"4444444444"},{"_id":"5880e44637893c04c87e30c0","name":"Tracy","email":"Tracy@asodj.com","number":"123412345"},{"_id":"5880e44637893c04c87e30c1","name":"tucker","email":"tucker@email.com","number":"1234456666"}]`

Comment: ok, and in your angularJS app ? what is the output of `console.log($scope.contactlist)` after the ajax call ?

Comment: `console.log(docs) ` prints the same json as my previous comment!

Comment: `console.log($scope.contactlist)` outputs `undefined`. So there is my error right?